# Eager load a subset of an associate entity in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

There is a bank entity and each bank has many rates associated with them.

```
class Bank < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rates
end

class Rate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

Each rate has `period` property which can be any number of months.

How do I eager load the rates of periods 3, 6, 12 and 60 when loading banks?

Also how to sort the rates in ascending order by period?

This is what I tried so far.

```
@banks = Bank.includes(:rates)
      .where(rates: {period: [3, 6, 12, 60]})
      .order("rates.period desc")
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You can simply try `Bank.includes(:rates).where(rates: { period: [3, 6, 12, 60] }).order('rates.period ASC')`

Comment: @RajdeepSingh added code I tried so far. But that gives me all rates of the bank

Comment: @nterms Just updated my answer, just a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve could be done easily by reversing the query you tried

```
rates = Rate.includes(:bank).where(period: [3, 6, 12, 60]).order('rates.period DESC')
```

To fetch the bank, just do `rates.first.bank`

Just a workaround, this won't fetch any unwanted `rate` records! Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to load a list of banks with their rates for above mentioned periods.